# Storing data (including images) from a rich text editor using reactjs, nodejs in mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb-atlas, rich-text-editor

I am making a blog website and want to allow users to insert images in between the text and style the data their way. I was able to setup the Quill rich text editor but can't happen to get the all the data, **including image data**, and store it in MongoDB Atlas database. I also want to show it later on, so how do I store the data and then retrieve it to display it in my ReactJS page.

I tried to store the data in a state and then store it in MongoDB but since it is all in the form of HTML it's of no use when I need to display the text and image apart from each other later on.

Answer (score 0):

There are typically 2 ways to store the images

1. Store the actual image as a physical file in the server
2. Store the Image as base64 and store as text in the Database

For #2, quill editor allows you to get the content of the Rich-Text Editor.

call the quill.getContents() to get the details of the image.
Your image can be copied from a website which will be embedded as a hyperlink or as a file from your computer then it will be encoded as base64

[Quill get contents](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getcontents)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `handlers` to intercept the image insert routine and store/upload the image separately. And then do some replace magic to update the  content to include the proper URLs.

```
var toolbar = quill.getModule('toolbar');
toolbar.addHandler('image', imageHandler); 

...

imageHandler = (image, callback) => {
  // Upload image
  ...
  const img = '<img src="uploadedImageUrl" height="50"/>';
  quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(quill.getSelection().index, img);
}
```